# How can I get a value from inside of function?

Tags: php

Is it possible to get values from inside a function and use those outside of the function?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
function cart() {
  foreach($_SESSION as $name => $value){
    if ($value>0) {
      if (substr($name, 0, 5)=='cart_') {
        $id = substr($name, 5, (strlen($name)-5));
        $get = mysql_query('SELECT id, name, price FROM products WHERE id='.mysql_real_escape_string((int)$id));

        while ($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)) {
          $sub = $get_row['price']*$value;
          echo $get_row['name'].' x '.$value.' @ &pound;'.number_format($get_row['price'], 2).' = &pound;'.number_format($sub, 2).'<a href="cart.php?remove='.$id.'">[-]</a> <a href="cart.php?add='.$id.'">[+]</a> <a href="cart.php?delete='.$id.'">[Delete]</a><br />';
        }
      }      
      $total += $sub ;
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Now my question is how can I get the value of `$total`?  I want to use that value outside of the function. I have 2 functions 1 cart and 1 discount.

I tried `return $total;` (inside of function)

For example

```
$final = cart () - discount ();
echo $final;
```

It echos out both function, but code which is inside of function doesn't do any mathematical operation.

Comment: So you tried `return $total;` in your `cart()` function?

Comment: You should never do echo inside functions like that. Because, if I want to run your function, I suddenly got unexpected output from you echo. A function should do one job, return a value, and then finished.

Comment: thanks jannis for pointout my problem that echo is my problem.

Answer (score 3):

You need to "return" the value.  See the [entry in the PHP manual for this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php).  Basically, `return` means "exit this function now".  Optionally, you can also provide some data that the function can return.

Just use the `return` statement:

```
<?php
  function cart()
  {
      foreach ($_SESSION as $name => $value) {
          if ($value > 0) {
              if (substr($name, 0, 5) == 'cart_') {
                  $id = substr($name, 5, (strlen($name) - 5));
                  $get = mysql_query('SELECT id, name, price FROM products WHERE id=' . mysql_real_escape_string((int)$id));
                  while ($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)) {
                      $sub = $get_row['price'] * $value;
                      echo $get_row['name'] . ' x ' . $value . ' @ &pound;' . number_format($get_row['price'], 2) . ' = &pound;' . number_format($sub, 2) . '<a href="cart.php?remove=' . $id . '">[-]</a> <a href="cart.php?add=' . $id . '">[+]</a> <a href="cart.php?delete=' . $id . '">[Delete]</a><br />';
                  }
              }
              $total += $sub;
          }
      }

      return $total;
  }
?>
```

Comment: hey i did that but its display the echo code too which is middle of my function look my buttom of question. and tell me the way of grabbing the only $total value

Answer (score 0):

Write `return $total;` inside the function

Answer (score 0):

If you put `return $total` at the very end of the function (right before the last curly brace), you should be able to use the result.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your can use global scope. I.e.

   ```
   $s = 1;
   function eee()
   {
    global $s;
    $s++;
   }
   echo $s;
   ```
2. Your can got var/return var... if your need return more that 1 value - use array

   ```
   function eee( $s)
   {
     return $s++;
   }
   eee($s=1);
   echo $s;
   ```

Prefer 2'd. Cause global scope operationing - may cause problems, when app become's large.